# How to randomize a number that informs variables

Tags: javascript, math, random

I have a game where one object from an array is made invisible at random. It's a random number generator that dictates which object is taken out of the array. The player guesses which vanished and wins.

I want to have it so at a button press the number randomizes again.

I tried doing this in a function and was able to successfully generate a random number, but the other variables cannot access that random number.

```
<script>    
function sortByOrder (x, y)
    {
        x = Math.random();
        if (x <0.5) return 1; else return -1;

        if (x.order < y.order) return -9;
        if (x.order == y.order) return 0;
        if (x.order > y.order) return 9;
    }

    var icons = new Array ();

        icons [0] = {img: "Animals/Ape.png", name: "APE", id: "p1"};
        icons [1] = {img: "Animals/Bat.png", name: "BAT", id: "p2"};
        icons [2] = {img: "Animals/Cat.png", name: "CAT", id: "p3"};
        icons [3] = {img: "Animals/Emu.png", name: "EMU", id: "p4"};
        icons [4] = {img: "Animals/Yak.png", name: "YAK", id: "p5"};
        icons [5] = {img: "Animals/Dog.png", name: "DOG", id: "p6"};
        icons [6] = {img: "Animals/Cow.png", name: "COW", id: "p7"};
        icons [7] = {img: "Animals/Rat.png", name: "RAT", id: "p8"};
        icons [8] = {img: "Animals/Pig.png", name: "PIG", id: "p9"};


    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

    var target = icons[rnd].name;

    var id = icons[rnd].id;

    icons.sort(sortByOrder);

    function randomize()
    {
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);    
    }
function showBack()
    {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    </script>
```

I'm new to Javascript so I'm aware this may have a very easy solution.

Comment: `if (x <0.5) return 1; else return -1;` ends at any case the function.

Comment: Can you please be more specific with what you mean by "but the other variables can't reach it"? Do you mean that you're able to successfully generate a random number, but the other variables cannot access that random number?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to successfully generate a new random number. The initial `icons` array and other variables don't need to access this new variable. Rather, this function needs to be able to set a new object to be invisible.

One way to approach this might be to change your `showBack` function to tak an argument, for example:

```
function showBack(idArg)
    {
    document.getElementById(idArg).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

Then, your new random number generating function can call `showBack` with its newly generated random number.